# What index would insure this query runs fast?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, inner-join

Hello I have 3 tables `person` and `rooms`, `room_guests`. I have millions of rows on each of these tables. I am essentially just trying to find all the times `cus_num = 2342424324` stayed at my hotel and what rooms he stayed in with the sql statement below (does what I want). However, when I run this statement, it is VERY slow! How can I speed it up? Honestly, I'm fairly sure my sql statement is badly written. Is there a better sql statement (I feel `INNER JOIN` might be very slow)? I know I can create indexes as well, but I am unsure on what columns need to be indexed together.

Primary Keys

- `person_id`
- `room_id`
- `guest_id`

**person**

```
person_id | cus_num
----------------------
1         | 82736424
2         | 238748923
3         | 32424
4         | 2342424324
```

**rooms**

```
room_id | name
----------------------
1       | Cool Room
2       | Hot Room
3       | Spring rooms
4       | apartment
```

**room_guests**

```
guest_id | room_id | person_id | last_update
----------------------------------------------------
1        | 1       | 3         | 2019-02-03 12:00:43
2        | 4       | 2         | 2020-04-23 19:30:53
3        | 2       | 3         | 2018-12-21 08:34:29
4        | 3       | 1         | 2020-11-15 10:04:08
5        | 3       | 4         | 2019-05-09 11:53:31
```

**sql statement**

```
SELECT rooms.name
FROM rooms
INNER JOIN room_guests ON rooms.room_id = room_guests.room_id
INNER JOIN person ON room_guests.person_id = person_id
WHERE person.cus_num = 2342424324
ORDER BY room_guests.last_update DESC
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . .

```
SELECT r.name
FROM rooms r JOIN
     room_guests rg
     ON r.room_id = rg.room_id JOIN
     person p
     ON rg.person_id = p.person_id
WHERE p.cus_num = 2342424324
ORDER BY rg.last_update DESC
```

I would recommend indexes on:

- `person(cus_num, person_id)`
- `room_guests(person_id, room_id)`
- `room(room_id)`

This handles the `where` clause and `join`s.  The query will still need to sort for the `order by`.

Comment: Can you explain to me how you chose these indexes and why you used `JOIN` rather than `inner join`?

Comment: Another question why did you index `cus_num` and `person_id` together and not just index `cus_num` by itself. Why does `room_id` in the `rooms` table need to be index? It would be the primary key (edited question to specify the primary keys)?

Comment: [How MySQL Uses Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html). "inner join" is the same as "join". Look at `EXPLAIN {query}` on the result. Including `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` in the question avoid  confusion. Primary keys are quite suitable and don't need to be reindexed.

Comment: "cus_num and person_id together". MySQL uses one index at a time per table. The WHERE clause need `cus_num`, hence it being first, but then needs to join room_guests using person_id. Because this is nice and convient in the index that will be used. If person_id was a primary key, it would be implicitly at the end of the index anyway.

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov . . . I use `JOIN` because I wanted to format the query so I could read it better and `JOIN` is simpler to type.  The explanation is that this starts with the `WHERE clause and then works its way through the joins.

Comment: Meanwhile, `guest_id` is useless _and_ slows things down.  More tips on many:many tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table